# Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer crashes

Tags: android, crash

I'm trying to use the new GoogleAPIClient and I get connected but whenever I make a call to Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer in the callback to onConnected() I get this:

```
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:   Cannot add data to empty builder
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at bgs.a(SourceFile:915)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gb$a$a.fI(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.fx.fp(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.gm.getCurrentPlayer(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.djs.android.tictactoe.startpage.ActivityStartPage.onConnected(ActivityStartPage.java:540)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ei.b(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.dy(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.d(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$2.onConnected(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ei.b(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ei.bo(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.b(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.a(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$b.ec(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-28 21:26:40.931: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Here the code where the GoogleAPIClient is being created.

```
mGoogleClientAPI = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
```

Here's the code for the OnConnected method.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing())
    {
        mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    String playerid = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(mGoogleClientAPI);

    Player plr = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleClientAPI);
    MySigninButton.PlayerSignedIn(plr);
}
```

I can access the leaderboards and the achievements just fine, I can also call Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId() with no problem.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have it set up is to build the Google API Client in the Activity class in the `onCreate()` method.

```
this.mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .setViewForPopups(this.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button))
    .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

The `isShowing()` method should be working in `onConnected()`, that would throw an NPE anyway.

You wouldn't be able to connect or get to the leaderboards without enabling multiplayer on the Google Play Console either, so that seems okay.

What was interesting was that you could access the Player ID.  This leads me to conclude that you should check to make sure the Player object you are trying to create is actually part of the API (maybe you are trying to set it to your own version of a Player object) and again making sure the Google Client is built and in place before `onConnected()` is called.

I didn't have a solid answer, but I have gone through this process with my own app, so I feel we can reach a solution.